# recursive function that finds depth of empty list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

i need to write a recursive function that finds the depth of an empty list of lists, and it can only have one parameter, which is the list used. there is a test driver code for the problem which ill include below. i cant use advanced python stuff like isinstance or max and map because my professor wont allow it. i also am not sure what the make_list_structure function does exactly so if someone can explain what that was well that would be great.

```
import random


def make_list_structure(max_depth, p=.8):
   if max_depth and random.random() < p:
       new_list = []
       for i in range(5):
           sub_list = make_list_structure(max_depth - 1, p * .9)
           if sub_list is not None:
               new_list.append(sub_list)
       return new_list

   return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(how_deep([[[], [], [], [[[]]]], []]))
    print(how_deep([]))
    print(how_deep([[], []]))
    print(how_deep([[[]], [], [[]], [[[]]]]))
    print(how_deep([[[[], [[]], [[[]]], [[[[]]]]]]]))
    print(how_deep([[[], []], [], [[], []]]))
```

Comment: what is random and p ? and why a range of 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short solution using `max` and `map`, and it's adaptation without it

```
def how_deep(values):
    if not values:
        return 1
    sub_depth = 0
    for value in values:
        val_depth = how_deep(value)
        if val_depth > sub_depth:
            sub_depth = val_depth
    return sub_depth + 1

def how_deep_nice(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        return 1 + max((how_deep_nice(item) for item in l), default=0)
    return 0
```

```
print(how_deep([[[], [], [], [[[]]]], []]))  # 5
print(how_deep([]))  # 1
print(how_deep([[], []]))  # 2
```